# css flexbox - how to align corresponding elements in "card" design?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

here is my example,
https://plnkr.co/edit/uj4Z7W8nT2CSQ34i150x

```
<style>
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}

#container {
  display : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items : center;
  flex-wrap : wrap;
  align-content : center;
}

.offer {
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  background : #eee;
  flex-basis : 20vw;
  min-height : 45vh;
  flex-direction : column;
  margin : 1vw;
  border-radius : 1vh;
}

p {
  padding : 1vw;
}

img {
  width : 7vw;
  height : auto;
  margin-top : 0.5vh;
  margin-bottom : 1vh;
}

button {
  margin-bottom : 0;
}
</style>
```

How to align img's, titles and paragraph's starts to some baselines to make all cards look more orderly?

I.e. the distance between card top and img, title, paragaraph should be the same.

In my code it has different margins.

Comment: In `#container` it's possible to set `align-items : baseline` - and goal achieved, but how to make cards have equal sizes?

Comment: what do you mean by making the cards have equal sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `justify-content: center;` from the `.offer` selector. That is the CSS that is vertically centering your content.

https://plnkr.co/edit/TCiW9x5AhbS72ZP9ZWJO

UPDATE:

You can use `margin-top:auto` on the button to push it to the bottom of the div.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8rZyTHueltxfS7OQxsB2

Comment: Thank you. And yet one question how to make button be on bottom of a card?  Neither  `margin-bottom : 0;` nor ` align-self : end;` don't work (if there are a lot of vertical space).

Comment: if `h3` title is too long, it's not centered by flexbox. Maybe, you know why?

Comment: @LexUshakov Just add this CSS `h3 {text-align:center;}` or if you want all the content to be centered add `.offer {text-align:center;}`

Comment: @LexUshakov  _WizardCoder_, the OP means when it wraps it won't center vertical, and with the existing markup one can't do that based on content wrapping. If one know it won't be more than 2 lines, a fixed height could be a hack.

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for clarifying, I didn't notice that. Lex Ushakov, you would be better to go with LGSon's solution. They know more than me about flex anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `offer` you can also make it work even if your i.e. head line would have different amount of lines.

By using the `order` property you can tell how they should align in a group without a wrapper

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}

#container {
  display : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  flex-wrap : wrap;
}

#container > * {
  flex-basis : 22vw;
  margin: 0 1vw;
  background: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container > .image {
  order: 1;
  padding : 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#container > h3 {
  order: 2;
  padding : 10px 0;
  text-align: center
}
#container > p {
  order: 3;
  padding: 1vw;
}
#container > .button {
  order: 4;
  padding : 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width : 7vw;
  height : auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Limited-offer-PNG-HD.png" alt="offer 1 description">
      </div>      
      <h3>offer 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem tenetur ad mollitia exercitationem fugit expedita est doloribus quia! Deserunt quia omnis molestias amet quibusdam accusamus? Minus doloremque deserunt earum neque natus. Corporis adipisci doloremque consectetur beatae incidunt? Veniam. 1</p>      
      <div class="button">
        <button>buy it!</button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Limited-offer-PNG-HD.png" alt="offer 1 description">
      </div>
      <h3>offer 2 which has a longer text</h3>
      <p>Adipisicing minus quam beatae beatae error. Laudantium vel officia eum perspiciatis atque laborum Vel tempora architecto eos laborum veniam Quis nihil numquam ab reiciendis sapiente dolor Dolor adipisci nihil officia. 2</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>buy it!</button>
      </div>

      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Limited-offer-PNG-HD.png" alt="offer 1 description">
      </div>
      <h3>offer 3</h3>
      <p>Consectetur debitis maxime accusamus explicabo cupiditate Itaque quaerat laboriosam nisi ipsa possimus consequuntur Est fugit necessitatibus tempore eveniet provident Optio esse asperiores tempore eius perspiciatis perferendis architecto, mollitia dicta. Nihil! 3</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>buy it!</button>
      </div>

      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Limited-offer-PNG-HD.png" alt="offer 1 description">
      </div>
      <h3>offer 4</h3>
      <p>Consectetur minima illo optio quod repellat Perspiciatis omnis sed provident distinctio doloremque Odit est magnam aliquid accusamus expedita impedit Eligendi ab et soluta laboriosam sunt Debitis quidem provident ducimus saepe! 4</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>buy it!</button>
      </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: thank you, it's interesting example, and it shows how to fix long title problem - I didn't notice that issue.